# Recursion with Tasks and WaitAll

Tags: c#, recursion, task-parallel-library

Basically here is the problem, I have a function "GetAllCandidates" that accepts a list, calculates something, alters the parameters and calls itself using Task.Factory.StartNew to calculate all possible outputs with different morphs of the original array.

```
    private void GetAllCandidates(List<int> values)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);

        for (var i = values.Count - 1; i >= 1; i --)
        {
           //Do work and calculations

           Task.Factory.StartNew(
                           () => GetAllCandidatePowers(newPowers)
           );
        }
    }
```

I need to fully utilize the cores on my CPU and wait for all tasks to finish, and here is the problem.

- If I call .Wait() for the task, my cores don't get utilized (CPU usage is very low), therefore the calculations don't finish quickly.
- Creating a global list for tasks and then calling WaitAll doesn't work because its a random recursive calls, the list of tasks isn't fully populated when my program reaches the call for WaitAll(), and also since the calculations are huge, I get an OutOfMemoryException when I try add my tasks to a global task list.

any hints, on how to proceed with such a problem?

Comment: Make GetAllCandidates keep a function-local list of tasks started. At the end of the function wait for them. This still provides parallelism as long as you start more than 1 task.

Comment: This seems to work, thanx, please write this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `GetAllCandidates` keep a function-local list of tasks started. At the end of the function wait for them. This still provides parallelism as long as you start more than 1 task.

Comment: This isn't the ideal solution, since you're blocking a thread at each step of the recursion. Even if task inlining occurs, the thread subsequently still needs to wait for the slowest task that it spawned. This is one of the cases where asynchronous parallelism (such as `Task.WhenAll`) can offer drastically better performance than blocking parallelism (`Task.WaitAll`).

Comment: @Douglas I agree. I'm not sure this should be accepted like the OP hinted at in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method (introduced in .NET 4.5) to unravel the parallelism at each step of your recursion:

```
private Task GetAllCandidates(List<int> values)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (var i = values.Count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        //Do work and calculations

        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAllCandidatePowers(newPowers));
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

This way, you would only need to wait on the outermost call of your `GetAllCandidates` method within your application (if at all), blocking just one thread.

**Edit**: Equivalent formulation of `for` loop using LINQ:

```
private Task GetAllCandidates(List<int> values)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, values.Count - 1).Reverse().Select(i =>
    {
        //Do work and calculations

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAllCandidatePowers(newPowers));
    });

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your goal is to increase the performance of the entire process. Assuming that the order in which the for-loop is executed is not important, you can use TPL. It would get you a faster result I think.

```
private void GetAllCandidates(List<int> values)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);

        Parallel.ForEach(test, item =>
        {
            //Do work and calculations
            var t = new Task().Run(GetAllCandidatePowers(newPowers));
            // Although if you are waiting here, you might as well just run it synchronously.
            t.Wait(); 
       );
    }
}
```

**Update: [Use PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to maintain order**

I have provided an example that uses PLINQ to run the operations in parallel and then return the result set in their original order. Unless these operations are expensive, or there are a large number of them, you might not find a big performance increase. If you are doing some heavy loaded work, or have a large quantity of items to run through, then this should help you out.

```
private void GetAllCandidates(List<int> values)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);

    values.AsParallel().AsOrdered().ForAll((item) => 
    {
        // Do stuff


        GetAllCandidates(newPowers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note well the comment about just running synchronously.  You will not often need to create tasks within a `Parallel.ForEach` loop, in this case it is wasteful (overhead with no benefit) to spawn the Task and wait on it.

Comment: Yeah, I left the Task.Run in there in the event that he was doing other stuff between `Task.Wait()` and `Task.Run()`. You are right in the fact that spinning off a task while already in a TPL call is needless, which is why I left my comment in the code about just running `Synchronously` :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use Parallel.Foreach, my loop is dependent on the proper sequence of values.

Comment: @TamimSalem, *"my loop is dependent on the proper sequence of values"*, this is somewhat conflicting. If you need parallelism, why do you care about the sequence? Say, you want to start tasks in the order 3-2-1. What if #2 finishes earlier than #3, and so does the recursion step started by #2? On a side note, check Stephen Toub's ["Recursion and Concurrency"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2008/01/31/7357135.aspx).

Comment: @TamimSalem I agree with Noseratio. If you are trying to improve performance, and start running things asynchronously, you are going to loose the order. You can either reconstruct the order, or you can look in to using the [AsParallel().AsOrdered()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460719(v=vs.110).aspx) PLINQ methods to maintain order. It will execute in parallel, then reconstruct the result set in the proper order for you. I provided an update to my answer showing a potential way to do this.